# How to console.log data after converting address into coordinates using google geocoding?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am developing an application where I need to console.log geo coordinates derived from geocoding text address. I have written the following code in javascript:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

   function address_to_coordinates(address_text) {
    var address = address_text;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        return results[0].geometry.location;

      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

  console.log(address_to_coordinates('London'));
```

For some reason, it prints out 'undefined' in console. Does anyone see the reason for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use callback

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

   function address_to_coordinates(address_text, callback) {
    var address = address_text;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        callback(results[0].geometry.location);

      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

address_to_coordinates('London', function(location){
  console.log(location);
});
```

Comment: If i try to get latitude only by using callback(results[0].geometry.location.latitude); in your code. I still get undefined, do you know why is that?

Comment: Because argument in callback function is already `results[0].geometry.location`